# How to use Sed to find a file pattern and append a variable value at end of line

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed, append

I am trying to install a Nagios plugin, the file is called nagios and is written in PERL - this file will help us integrate our Nagios docker alerting system with slack.

What I need to do is to use sed to open the file, find a specific pattern on lines 120 and 304 and append a content of variable at end of each line.

​

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
​
# go into temp dir and do the following
cd /tmp/ && wget https://raw.github.com/tinyspeck/services-examples/master/nagios.pl
mv /tmp/nagios.pl /tmp/slack_nagios.pl && chmod +x /tmp/slack_nagios.pl
​
# define two variables adding1 and adding2, then add value to each one 
read -d '' adding1 <<"BLOCK"
-field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$"
-field SERVICEDESC="$SERVICEDESC$"
-field SERVICESTATE="$SERVICESTATE$"
-field SERVICEOUTPUT="$SERVICEOUTPUT$"
-field NOTIFICATIONTYPE="$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$"
BLOCK
​
read -d '' adding2 <<"BLOCK"
-field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$"
-field HOSTSTATE="$HOSTSTATE$"
-field HOSTOUTPUT="$HOSTOUTPUT$"
-field NOTIFICATIONTYPE="$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$"
BLOCK
​
## Print the two new variables
echo $adding1
​
echo $adding2
​
#### Now use seed to change the content of slack_nagios.pl file and save it as new file
echo "Execute sed"
​
# On file lines 31 to 50 uncomment it 
sed -e '31,50 s/#//' \
    -e 's/my $opt_token = ""/my $opt_token = "someTokenHere"/' \
    -e 's/foo.slack.com/somedomainName.slack.com/' \
    # Add toke info and replace slack domain name
    -e 's/#alerts/#nagios_alerts/' \
    -e 's/#ops/#nagios_alerts/' \
    # Find two patterns in the file and replace with nagios_alerts
    -e 's|/usr/local/bin|/usrPATH/local/nagiosPATH/etc/dirPATH|g' \
    # Replace the deafult path by the new path
    ###HERE IS WHERE I HAVIN PROBLEMS##
    -e '44 s/^nagios_alerts\|\'$'\|${adding1}|g' \
    -e '49 s/^nagios_alerts\|\'$'\|${adding2}|g' \
    # What I want to do is, on lines 44 and line 49 find the pattern nagios_alert
    # And append the value of $adding1 at end of line 44 and append the value of $adding2 on line 49
    # But I am getting the following error [ sed: 1: "44 s/^nagios_alerts///| ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/' ]
    <slack_nagios.pl >slack_new_nagios.pl
​
​
​
# Count the number of line on the file to confirm that is correct
nbLines=$(cat -n slack_new_nagios.pl | tail -n 1 | cut -f1 | xargs)
echo $nbLines
​
#echo $file 
echo "All Done"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't spend enough time to understand your specific example but the general problem you want to solve is

```
sed '120,304{/pattern/s/$/add_this_to_end_of_line/}' file
```

Note that this can be translated to awk which will give you more power if you need to do more complex changes

```
awk 'NR>=120 && NR<=304 && /pattern/{$0=$0 "add this"}1' file
```

Comment: Hi thanks @karaka, your answered help me clear some doubts I had, for what I needed to be done. Finally I have managed to make the script to execute do what I were looking to accomplish.